# Error al ingresar datos a MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Lo que pasa es que todo funcionaba bien hasta que añadi codsem -> que es codigo semestre.
Ahora me dice asistencia registrada cuando no existe el alumno y ni si quiera.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
echo 'Connected succedsrssfully';
mysql_select_db('controlasistencia') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM asistencia';
$codes=$_POST['codes'];
$coddo=$_POST['coddo'];
$codsem=$_POST['codsem'];
$query_search = "Insert into asistencia (coddo,codsem,codes) values ('".$codes."','".$coddo."','".$codsem."')";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Como podría hacer para que cuando estudiante no exista en la tabla y yo trate de ingresar su asistencia me de un error

Aqui dejo la tabla asistencia

```
CREATE TABLE `asistencia` (
`coddo` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`codsem` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`codes` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`fecha` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Y sus key

```
ALTER TABLE `asistencia`
ADD KEY `codsem` (`codsem`),
ADD KEY `codes` (`codes`),
ADD KEY `coddo` (`coddo`);
```

Comment: que error te sale?

Comment: Dice asistencia registrada cuando el estudiante no esta en la base de datos

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar la estructura de la tabla `asistencia `, con indices y demás? Pareciera que la nueva columna `codsem` la haz definido como un indice `UNIQUE` o algo por el estilo.

Comment: esta definida como indice

Comment: ¿Puedes describir la tabla `estudiante` también? ¿Cuales columnas relacionan las tablas `estudiante` y `asistencia`?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE `estudiantes` (
  `nombres` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `codigo` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `codse` bigint(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

Comment: solo como comentario, en PHP ya no es recomendable utilizar la libreria `mysql`, para evitarte problemas en el futuro utiliza `mysqli` o `PDO`

Comment: ¿Cómo llevas el problema? ¿Lo solucionaste? ¿Alguna respuesta te ayudó? Si es así, por favor, vota las respuestas que te ayudaron y marca como solución aquella que te solucionara la pregunta. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La mejor manera, es la que te han mencionado, creado relaciones entre dichas tablas, con `claves foráneas`.

También tienes que tener en cuenta que `mysql` ha quedado obsoleta según la documentación oficial y en su lugar debería usar `mysqli`, o personalmente te aconsejo `sentencias preparadas`.

> Manual sentencias preparadas: 
>   https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php

Aun así, voy a dejar un ejemplo, como podría quedar sin `claves foráneas`, pero simplemente haciendo una comprobación si existen alguna relación, y en caso si existe inserta los datos.

Para ello hacemos un `SELECT` en la tabla estudiante donde imaginemos que has puesto la columna código con la misma relación que tu tabla asistencia, columna codsem, importante que el código sea único `(unique)`, para poder trabajar como identificador.

El código podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php    
//Data conexión.
$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$contrasena = '';
$base_datos = 'controlasistencia';

//Conexión.
$link = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $contrasena, $base_datos);

//Comprobamos conexión.
if (!$link) {
    die("No se pude conectar: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 

echo "Conectado con exito";

//Obtenemos datos de manera mas segura (mysqli_real_escape_string).
$codes = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['codes']);
$coddo = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['coddo']);
$codsem = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['codsem']);

//Sentencia, comprobación existencia.
$existe = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT codigo FROM estudiantes WHERE codigo='$codsem' ");
//Comprobamos existencia.
if (mysqli_num_rows($existe) === 1) {

  //Sentencia, insertar registro.
  $insertar = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO asistencia (coddo,codsem,codes) VALUES ('".$codes"','".$coddo"','".$codsem"')");

  if ($insertar) {    
    echo "El registro se inserto con exito.";
  } else {
    echo "Hubo un error, no se inserto el registro.";
  }

} else { //Caso falso, tu mensaje de error.
  //Mensaje.
  echo "0 registros encontrados.";
}
//Cerramos conexión.
mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo el uso de [claves foráneas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_for%C3%A1nea). Aquí tienes la [documentación oficial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Ejemplo:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `asistencia`
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (codes)
    REFERENCES estudiantes(codigo)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

De esta manera, si no hay ningún elemento en la tabla `estudiantes` cuyo campo `codigo` no concuerde con el campo `codes` de la tabla `asistencia` te dará un error y no te permitirá insertar el registro en la tabla `asistencia`.

Edito: Para más información, el error que te generará será un código [ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_no_referenced_row_2). Te será útil si quieres capturarlo con [`mysql_errno()`](http://php.net/mysql-errno).

PD: Te recomiendo encarecidamente que migres tu código a [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) o [PDO](http://php.net/pdo-mysql) (yo prefiero usar este último). Aprender o seguir usando las funciones `mysql_*` es tiempo perdido. A partir de la versión 5.5 se consideraron obsoletas y han sido eliminadas en la versión 7.

Answer (score -1):

Podrías hacer un select antes para determinar si existe o no un estudiante. Luego, si no existe ese estudiante, no insertas; si existe insertas.

```
// Buscar si existe estudiante.
    $query_estudiante = "Select * from estudiate where estudiante_id = $codes")";    

    // Si existe un registro, inserta
    if (count($query_estudiante) > 0){
        $query_search = "Insert into asistencia (coddo,codsem,codes) values ('".$codes."','".$coddo."','".$codsem."')";
        $query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: De hecho esta es una solución al problema, tendría que ejemplificar su respuesta.

Comment: @Cig ya esta. Gracias